# MySql: Same select count(*) query returns different results if invoked within a function or outside

Tags: mysql, count

Well, as simple as that. The following query returns 1:

```
select count(*) as Total from conversations
where TargetUserID = 2
  and LastMessageSenderUserID = StarterUserID
  and TotalMessages > 0
  and Answered = 0
  and (@ReadDate := GetConversationReadDate(ID)) is not null
  and @ReadDate < date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)
```

I copied the very same code in the body of a stored function with one parameter user_id:

```
return (select count(*) as Total from conversations
where TargetUserID = user_id
  and LastMessageSenderUserID = StarterUserID
  and TotalMessages > 0
  and Answered = 0
  and (@ReadDate := GetConversationReadDate(ID)) is not null
  and @ReadDate < date_sub(now(), interval 1 day))
```

However the latter, called with user_id = 2, returns 0. It is not deterministic and flagged as 'reads sql data'.

Comment: What are the datatype of both the field *TargetUserID* and the parameter *user_id*? If you are comparing two floats you will always get erratic results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same variable in two parts of the `where` clause.  This is not safe.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of execution of the subclauses of a where.  You should do something like:

```
and GetConversationReadDate(ID) < date_sub(now(), interval 1 day))
```

This will automatically fail if the value returned is `NULL`, so the `NULL` check is redundant.

Here is the quote from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement.

Comment: Feels like programming in scheme XD Thanks